# TransactionScope check if transaction commited ok

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, transactionscope

Hello is there a way to check if a transaction using TransactionScope was committed or rolledback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual Commit is not happening until the TransactionScope is disposed. If the Commit fails for any reason an exception will be thrown. You should Catch that exception and put your logic for failed transaction in the Catch block. If no exception has been thrown you should be assured that Commit was successful. If for any reasons that I cant think of, you don't trust the framework, you can always create another Scope and query the results to make sure they have been applied.

```
var transactionFailed = false;
try
{
    using (var tx = new TransactionScope())
    {
        tx.Complete();
    }
}
catch (TransactionAbortedException ex)
{
    transactionFailed = true;
    writer.WriteLine("TransactionAbortedException Message: {0}", ex.Message);

}
catch (ApplicationException ex)
{
    transactionFailed = true;
    writer.WriteLine("ApplicationException Message: {0}", ex.Message);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    transactionFailed = true;
    writer.WriteLine("Exception Message: {0}", ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: FWIW, ApplicationException is considered a dead class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just add a variable and check it.

```
bool txExecuted;

using (var tx = new TransactionScope())
{
 //code
 if (code was OK)
 {
   tx.Complete();
   txExecuted = true;
 }

}
```

Comment: [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) does not have a Commit method. It does have a [Complete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.complete.aspx) method but calling that method doesn't necessarily commit the transaction.

Comment: I want to know if something went wrong with the transaction not in the code.

Comment: @david2342 - if the end of the Transaction scope is reached and Complete is not called successfully then its rolled back and the variable is not set.

Comment: @StingyJack, if Complete is called it doesn't mean the transaction is committed. There might be another ambient (higher level) transaction scope that isn't completed yet.

Comment: @lightbricko Then you need to put the bool in the correct place, or use more than one. This does answer OP's question, as it will tell you if this transaction was completed or not.

Comment: @StingyJack, Putting the bool at the right place (the outermost TransactionScope) is the way!

Comment: @lightbricko - yeah, but you are ASSUMING he has multiple nested TXS. This is not specified in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to msdn documentation
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.complete(v=vs.110).aspx

// The Complete method commits the transaction. If an exception has been thrown,
// Complete is not  called and the transaction is rolled back.

completeCallback method will be call only after sucessfull transactionScope.Complete() method execution

So you can use function:

```
public bool TryRunTransaction(Action transactionAction)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                transactionAction();
                transactionScope.Complete();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (TransactionAbortedException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```